# Python Selenium only finds the first element on page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is my second question on StackOverflow so please be kind to me.

I'm trying to get some data from autoscout24 via Selenium and Python. The URL of the webpage is: [Link](https://www.autoscout24.de/lst/bmw/80637-m%C3%BCnchen?&sort=standard&desc=0&offer=J%2CU%2CO%2CD%2CS&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&lon=11.53631&lat=48.16235&zip=80637%20M%C3%BCnchen&zipr=20&cy=D&priceto=10000&fregfrom=2010&atype=C&page=1)

I have basically two problems I don't get any solution for:

1. I don't get any values for mileage etc. from the first page.
2. The value for Mileage, Production Date and Performance on the upcoming pages is always the same (the first value from the page).

The HTML structure is the following:

```
<ul data-item-name="vehicle-details">
<div class="cldt-summary-vehicle-data" data-item-name="vehicle-data">
<ul data-item-name="vehicle-details">
<li>
    126.000 km
</li>
<li>
    05/2012
</li>
<li>
    105 kW (143 PS)
</li>
```

I have stored all result pages in a list and iterating over it, trying to get all the data from each page.

```
def scrape(self, results):
        self.results = results
        df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'price', 'mileage', 'productiondate', 'performance'])
        carData = {}
        for result in self.results:
            sys.stdout.write('\r Progressing: ' + result)
            self.driver.get(result)
            #print('Extracting site {}'.format(result))
            time.sleep(numpy.random.randint(numpy.random.randint(1,2), numpy.random.randint(2, 3))) # create a random waiting time somewhere between 1 and 3 seconds
            for car in self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cl-list-element.cl-list-element-gap'):
                carName = car.find_element_by_class_name('cldt-summary-makemodel.sc-font-bold.sc-ellipsis').text # name of the car
                carPrice = car.find_element_by_class_name('cldt-price.sc-font-xl.sc-font-bold').text # price of the car
                carMileage = car.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="cldt-summary-vehicle-data"]/ul/li[1]').text # mileage of the car
                carProductionDate = car.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="cldt-summary-vehicle-data"]/ul/li[2]').text # production date of the car MM/YYYY
                carPerformance = car.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="cldt-summary-vehicle-data"]/ul/li[3]').text # performance in PS or KW
                # add car extras here
                carData = pandas.Series({'name': carName,
                                        'price': carPrice,
                                        'mileage': carMileage,
                                        'productiondate': carProductionDate,
                                        'performance': carPerformance})
                #print(carData)
                df = df.append(carData, ignore_index = True)
        
        return df
```

The result I get for CarData is the following. From the second page, I get the names right. But I only get the first value for mileage, production date, and performance from the page.

```
        name       price     mileage productiondate      performance
0    BMW 118                                                        
1                                                                   
2                                                                   
3                                                                   
4                                                                   
..       ...         ...         ...            ...              ...
129  BMW 320   € 9.999,-  153.311 km        05/2012  105 kW (143 PS)
130  BMW 125   € 9.999,-  153.311 km        05/2012  105 kW (143 PS)
131  BMW 120   € 9.999,-  153.311 km        05/2012  105 kW (143 PS)
132  BMW 320  € 10.000,-  153.311 km        05/2012  105 kW (143 PS)
133  BMW 320  € 10.000,-  153.311 km        05/2012  105 kW (143 PS)
```

If you have any idea, what I'm doing wrong or could do better, please tell me.

Comment: From your two questions and the HTML, I am not very sure what you are looking for ? May be you can also post ```carData``` and update your question accordingly.

Comment: +1 to @SariqShaikh. Also, the page URL would be super helpful, so we can check the HTML and validate the locators.

Comment: It seems that you are overwritting df in this line: ``` df = df.append(carData, ignore_index = True) ``` I believe you need to just do it like this ``` df.append(carData, ignore_index = True) ```